# window.location.href and **.replace concatenates the URL instead of replacing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've got an issue, using `window.location.href` or `windown.location.replace()` seems to concatenate my URL instead of replacing and redirecting.

Here's my code:

```
$("#languages p").click(function() {
    $language = $(this).text();
    $lang = $language.toLowerCase();

    var url = 'www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/';
    var position = url.indexOf('/') + 12;

    window.location.replace([url.slice(0, position), $lang, url.slice(position)].join(''));
});
```

Live preview at: www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp   --- the PL/EN/DE/RU boxes in top-right corner

What am I doing wrong? Or is that wordpress that messes it up?

Comment: you need to specify a protocol also, i.e. `http://` in your case with URL

Comment: so easy yet got me confused, thank you! works!